# Does CPAN installing of new modules impact Perl-CGI applications on same live production server?

Tags: perl, cgi, installation, live, cpan

I have some Perl/CGI programs on a CentOS Linux webserver. I wish to write further applications that require Perl modules not currently installed.

Does running CPAN on the same live production server impact these programs (which currently don't use the modules, obviously) in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's one possible way that it could have an effect. If the modules you are installing require newer versions of modules that you are already using, then it's possible that these newer versions could affect the behaviour of your existing programs.

For example. Suppose you currently have version 1.0 of Foo.pm installed. You now want to install a new module called Bar.pm. But Bar.pm depends on version 2.0 of Foo.pm - and CPAN will therefore pull in a newer version of Foo.pm as part of the installation of Bar.pm. In the worse case scenario, the author of Foo.pm could have completely changed the interface of the module between versions. In that case any program that uses Foo.pm 1.0 could stop working when version 2.0 is installed.

It's very unlikely as Perl modules usually work hard to maintain backwards compatibility. But this is why we have testing environments and test suites and don't put stuff into production without testing it thoroughly first.

Comment: One example that I encountered recently was in List::MoreUtils in the 'none' function - in the latest ("non-stable") release, its behaviour with respect to empty lists has been reversed. (Some naughty distribution required this version, and I didn't notice it being upgraded in all the spew from everything else being installed.)

Comment: Thanks davorg +1. I see what you mean about dependencies - whereby new modules requiring versions of those already used by my current programs - that situation could be a problem for me. I don't have the luxury of a test server, a wish-list idea for me would be to be able to "containerize" several of Perl installations on the same machine so that installs are only local to a Perl installation in a particular container, kind of like a more fine grained virtualisation/vmware system.

Comment: Accepted davorg's answer. To add to it, I guess I should work out how to find out the dependencies of a new module, and build a list from this of any existing modules that would be replaced, and then assess the risk, perhaps also using a diff tool such as Beyond Compare to check interface differences as davorg suggested would be one of the reasons for a failure scenario. Thanks.

Comment: In fact, I think davorg's suggestion is perhaps the only way that such a install of new perl modules would have an impact. Others: feel free to add comment or answer. I would accept davorg's answer but if there are other situations then I would create an answer myself with an aggregate of these and accept it, crediting you all and also upscoring you all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd describe a test server as "a luxury" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the newly-installed modules will be available to your Perl/CGI environment, *provided* that the `perl` you use to install the modules from CPAN is the same `perl` that the web server uses to run the Perl/CGI applications.  e.g., If you install the modules using `/opt/local/bin/perl` and the web server executes the apps under `/usr/bin/perl`, then the two `perl`s will (usually) each have their own set of installed modules, so the web server won't see them.