# CPAN: How to overcome "Please login with USER and PASS." "Passive mode refused." errors?

Tags: perl, installation, cpan, perl-module

How do I overcome "Please login with USER and PASS." "Passive mode refused." errors? - when attempting a CPAN module install from within the cpan shell / cpan> prompt

From the output logs to the terminal it appears to be able to connect to an external Perl/CPAN ftp site from my work server but the remote machine is asking for username/password and is rejecting the connection due to my being in passive mode.

( I've tested ftp.perl.org separately and have been able to successfully login with user:anonymous password:anonymous )

So,

1. Where do I put the username/password for CPAN program to supply to this remote perl/cpan machine? ( I assume the username is: anonymous, password: anonymous )
2. Where do I make a setting to say that I'm in the correct mode (passive/non-passive) such that the remote perl/cpan machine will accept my connection
3. Anything else I should do after I have resolved these issues?

Terminal output below, followed by Config.pm in CPAN folder on my server.

My machine is a CentOS Linux machine.

I'm trying to get Date::Calc successfully installed - my ultimate aim. Thanks.

Can't find any answers after a search here and on the internet.

```
# cpan
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.7602)
ReadLine support available (try 'install Bundle::CPAN')

cpan> install Date::Calc
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /root/.cpan/Metadata
Warning: Found only 0 objects in /root/.cpan/Metadata
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok
Fetching with LWP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[404] message[File '01mailrc.txt.gz' not found]
Fetching with Net::FTP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Couldn't fetch 01mailrc.txt.gz from ftp.perl.org

Trying with "/usr/bin/links -source" to get
    ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
ELinks: FTP file error

System call "/usr/bin/links -source "ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > /root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt"
returned status 1 (wstat 256)
Warning: expected file [/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz] doesn't exist

Trying with "/usr/bin/wget -O -" to get
    ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
--2010-11-08 15:50:51--  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
           => `-'
Resolving ftp.perl.org... 64.27.65.115, 168.143.19.69
Connecting to ftp.perl.org|64.27.65.115|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /pub/CPAN/authors ... done.
==> SIZE 01mailrc.txt.gz ... 174301
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR 01mailrc.txt.gz ...
No such file `01mailrc.txt.gz'.


System call "/usr/bin/wget -O - "ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  > /root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt"
returned status 1 (wstat 256)
Warning: expected file [/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz] doesn't exist
Issuing "/usr/bin/ftp -n"
Trying 64.27.65.115...
usage: user username [password] [account]
Local directory now /root/.cpan/sources/authors
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Passive mode refused.
Bad luck... Still failed!
Can't access URL ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.

Please check, if the URLs I found in your configuration file
(ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/) are valid. The urllist can be edited. E.g.
with 'o conf urllist push ftp://myurl/'

Could not fetch authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[404] message[File '02packages.details.txt.gz' not found]
Fetching with Net::FTP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Couldn't fetch 02packages.details.txt.gz from ftp.perl.org

Trying with "/usr/bin/links -source" to get
    ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
ELinks: FTP file error

System call "/usr/bin/links -source "ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz"  > /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt"
returned status 1 (wstat 256)
Warning: expected file [/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz] doesn't exist

Trying with "/usr/bin/wget -O -" to get
    ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
--2010-11-08 15:51:12--  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
           => `-'
Resolving ftp.perl.org... 64.27.65.115, 168.143.19.69
Connecting to ftp.perl.org|64.27.65.115|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /pub/CPAN/modules ... done.
==> SIZE 02packages.details.txt.gz ... 950491
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR 02packages.details.txt.gz ...
No such file `02packages.details.txt.gz'.


System call "/usr/bin/wget -O - "ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz"  > /root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt"
returned status 1 (wstat 256)
Warning: expected file [/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz] doesn't exist
Issuing "/usr/bin/ftp -n"
Trying 64.27.65.115...
usage: user username [password] [account]
Local directory now /root/.cpan/sources/modules
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Passive mode refused.
Bad luck... Still failed!
Can't access URL ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz.

Please check, if the URLs I found in your configuration file
(ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/) are valid. The urllist can be edited. E.g.
with 'o conf urllist push ftp://myurl/'

Could not fetch modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz
LWP failed with code[404] message[File '03modlist.data.gz' not found]
Fetching with Net::FTP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Couldn't fetch 03modlist.data.gz from ftp.perl.org

Trying with "/usr/bin/links -source" to get
    ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz
ELinks: FTP file error

System call "/usr/bin/links -source "ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz"  > /root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data"
returned status 1 (wstat 256)
Warning: expected file [/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz] doesn't exist

Trying with "/usr/bin/wget -O -" to get
    ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz
--2010-11-08 15:51:31--  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz
           => `-'
Resolving ftp.perl.org... 64.27.65.115, 168.143.19.69
Connecting to ftp.perl.org|64.27.65.115|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD /pub/CPAN/modules ... done.
==> SIZE 03modlist.data.gz ... 182988
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR 03modlist.data.gz ...
No such file `03modlist.data.gz'.


System call "/usr/bin/wget -O - "ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz"  > /root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data"
returned status 1 (wstat 256)
Warning: expected file [/root/.cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz] doesn't exist
Issuing "/usr/bin/ftp -n"
Trying 64.27.65.115...
usage: user username [password] [account]
Local directory now /root/.cpan/sources/modules
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Please login with USER and PASS.
Passive mode refused.
Bad luck... Still failed!
Can't access URL ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz.

Please check, if the URLs I found in your configuration file
(ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/) are valid. The urllist can be edited. E.g.
with 'o conf urllist push ftp://myurl/'

Could not fetch modules/03modlist.data.gz
Going to write /root/.cpan/Metadata
Warning: Cannot install Date::Calc, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /Date::Calc/

to find objects with matching identifiers.
```

/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN/Config.pm :-

```
# This is CPAN.pm's systemwide configuration file. This file provides
# defaults for users, and the values can be changed in a per-user
# configuration file. The user-config file is being looked for as
# ~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm.

$CPAN::Config = {
  'build_cache' => q[10],
  'build_dir' => q[/root/.cpan/build],
  'cache_metadata' => q[1],
  'cpan_home' => q[/root/.cpan],
  'dontload_hash' => {  },
  'ftp' => q[/usr/bin/ftp],
  'ftp_proxy' => q[],
  'getcwd' => q[cwd],
  'gpg' => q[/usr/bin/gpg],
  'gzip' => q[/bin/gzip],
  'histfile' => q[/root/.cpan/histfile],
  'histsize' => q[100],
  'http_proxy' => q[],
  'inactivity_timeout' => q[0],
  'index_expire' => q[1],
  'inhibit_startup_message' => q[0],
  'keep_source_where' => q[/root/.cpan/sources],
  'links' => q[/usr/bin/links],
  'make' => q[/usr/bin/make],
  'make_arg' => q[],
  'make_install_arg' => q[],
  'makepl_arg' => q[],
  'ncftp' => q[],
  'ncftpget' => q[],
  'no_proxy' => q[],
  'pager' => q[/usr/bin/less],
  'prerequisites_policy' => q[ask],
  'scan_cache' => q[atstart],
  'shell' => q[/bin/bash],
  'tar' => q[/bin/tar],
  'term_is_latin' => q[1],
  'unzip' => q[/usr/bin/unzip],
  'urllist' => [q[ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/]],
  'wget' => q[/usr/bin/wget],
};
1;
__END__
```

**Update:**

In response to daxim's comment on his answer: "You can edit comments. - Either edit Config.pm, the key urllist is an arrayref of strings; or run o conf urllist at the CPAN prompt. – daxim 16 hours ago" - I tried your suggestions below, daxim:

First I tried:

```
  cpan> o conf urllist
    urllist
        ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/
Type 'o conf' to view configuration edit options
```

Followed instructions (i.e. 3rd example bullet under heading "changing of list values: o conf KEY SHIFT|UNSHIFT|PUSH|POP|SPLICE|LIST" at http://search.cpan.org/~andk/CPAN-1.9402/lib/CPAN.pm#changing ) to add a http mirror from: http://www.cpan.org/SITES.html

```
cpan> o conf urllist http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/www.cpan.org/ ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/

cpan> o conf urllist
    urllist
        ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/
Type 'o conf' to view configuration edit options


cpan>
```

So from the above, my HTTP mirror was not added. Can anyone offer some advice?

So then I tried: "Either edit Config.pm, the key urllist is an arrayref of strings; ":

The relevant snippet in Config.pm is:

```
 'urllist' => [q[ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/]],
  'wget' => q[/usr/bin/wget],
```

How would my arrayref look here - with my list of mirrors. i.e. tell me how I should edit it, please.

**Update 2:**

The instructions given in http://search.cpan.org/~andk/CPAN-1.9402/lib/CPAN.pm#changing (3rd example bullet), to add a URL to the urllist are incomplete, i.e. wrong, they missed out the push. The successful command is:

```
[root CPAN]# cpan
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.7602)
ReadLine support available (try 'install Bundle::CPAN')

cpan> o conf urllist push http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/www.cpan.org/

cpan> o conf urllist
    urllist
        ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/
        http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/www.cpan.org/
Type 'o conf' to view configuration edit options


cpan>
```

From:

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=551175

**Other important things:**

Beforehand, must check if installing a new module, whether or not it also installs dependencies - i.e other modules - and if they are newer versions of those existing on the machine and therefore if their behaviour or interface has changed that would impact existing applications running on the machine: [Does CPAN installing of new modules impact Perl-CGI applications on same live production server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124843/does-cpan-installing-of-new-modules-impact-perl-cgi-applications-on-same-live-pro)

**Update 3:**

It would appear that editing the urllist is not persistent, as, on re-entering cpan after previous exit, only the ftp entry remains.

```
cpan> o conf urllist
    urllist
        ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/
Type 'o conf' to view configuration edit options
```

Comment: `o conf help` → `o conf commit`.  Or set the option `auto_commit` to `1`.

Comment: +1 for commit suggestion above, daxim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overcome FTP problems (it's a really stupid network protocol) by [selecting a HTTP mirror](http://mirrors.cpan.org/).

Comment: OK thanks and can you give an example as to how I would configure the CPAN program on my server to select a HTTP mirror, once I have decided on one to choose? I'm looking for snippets showing the changes to CPAN code/script/config files, e.g. in Config.fm

Comment: Does http://mirrors.cpan.org/ work? Is it supposed to? I get "page cannot be displayed"

Comment: You can edit comments. - Either edit `Config.pm`, the key `urllist` is an arrayref of strings; or [run `o conf urllist` at the CPAN prompt](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#changing).

Comment: Updated the question with outcomes of your above suggestion - put the outcomes in the question as commenting here loses formatting.

Comment: +1 And accepted answer, thanks daxim, I've updated the question with the detail regarding the commands to use to carry out your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting the username/password prompt, but I believe that you should be able to set it to the values you specified above by creating a `~/.netrc` file that looks something like this

```
machine ftp.perl.org
   login anonymous
   password anonymous@cpan.org
```

or you can force all ftp requests to be automatically anonymous unless specified otherwise by putting this line in `~/.netrc`

```
default login anonymous password anonymous@cpan.org
```

Every FTP client and library I have ever used honors the `.netrc` file.  It is one way to keep the password for a site out of your source code, even if it is sitting in plain text.

Comment: thanks I will try that and see what if it gets me further into solving the problem. is it a surprise that the cpan asks for this then? do you not get that yourself if you try that? presumably i guess if you are not then this is due to you using your own suggestion of ~/.netrc

Comment: I don't interact with CPAN on a regular basis as my distribution has most everything I need.  I've had to deal with `.netrc` on other projects.  I like the comment above that suggests you move over to the HTTP mirror, although I'm not sure how that is configured.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misdiagnosing the problem -- you're encountering errors much sooner, e.g. in the lines

> Fetching with LWP:
>     ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
>   LWP failed with code[404] message[File '01mailrc.txt.gz' not found]

Do you have a proxy or a firewall set up between this machine and the internet? This connection is failing.

Comment: yes I do have a proxy/firewall as the server is running from an internal network within the company that i work for. But I don't know why the connection you say is failing, if I am able to connect via ftp  to external ftp.perl.org - why would one connection work and not another? Thoughts? Moving on from that, if my HTTP proxy is myproxy.subdomain.mycompany.com then would I need to put this in Config.fm to overcome the connection fail you mention? Would I put it in entry http_proxy e.g. 'http_proxy' => q[myproxy.subdomain.mycompany.com] ? What about password/username and port too?